# Show that $\sum_{j=0}^{2J+1} (-1)^j \sum_{d|(m,n) \, \omega(d)=j} 1 \le 1_m (n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory

I’d like to show that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{2J+1} (-1)^j \sum_{d|(m,n)\\ \omega(d)=j} 1 \le 1_m (n)$$ for any integer $J\ge 0$,

where $\omega(d)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $d$ and
$1_m(n) = 1$ if and only if $(m,n)=1$, otherwise it is $0$.

All I have done is the followings:

I know that

$$\sum_{j=0}^{2J+1} {k \choose j}(-1)^j \le 1_m(n)=(1-1)^k$$

where $k$ is the number of prime factors of $(m,n)$.

and

$$\sum_{d|(m,n) \\ \omega(d)=j} 1 \le {k \choose j}$$

What I want to show is “alternating sum” of above terms,

I’ve tried to use above two inequalities, but I couldn’t proceed it further.

And a few calculation by hands convinces me it is true.

Any hint and suggestion will be appreciated.

Edit:

I've shown that if $(m,n)={p_1}^{a_1}{p_2}^{a_2}\dots{p_l}^{a_l}$, where $p_i$ are primes and $l$ is odd, then

$$\sum_{j=0}^{l}(-1)^j \sum_{d|(m,n) \\ \omega(d)=j} 1 = A \prod_{i=1}^{j} \left(\frac{1}{a_i} -1\right), $$

where $A := \prod_{i=1}^{j} a_i$.

so if $l$ is odd, then the above sum should be non-positive.

then what I'd like to show follows.

But it left the case $2J+1 < l$.

Comment: @TravorLZH What is m? Do you mean that m came from (m,n)?

Comment: There was a typo. The correct formula should be $\sum_{0\le j\le m}\binom kj(-1)^j=(-1)^m\binom{k-1}m$

Comment: @TravorLZH How do you use it the sum over $\omega(d)=j$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to proving

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{2J+1}(-1)^j\sum_{\substack{d|n\\\omega(d)=j}}1\le
\begin{cases}
1 & n=1 \\
0 & n>1
\end{cases}
$$

Suppose $\omega(n)=k$. Then the LHS can be written using binomial coefficients:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{2J+1}(-1)^j\sum_{\substack{d|n\\\omega(d)=j}}1=\sum_{j=0}^{2J+1}(-1)^j\binom kj
$$

To obtain a closed form for the RHS, we define the following sequence:

$$
a_{t,k}=\sum_{0\le j\le t}(-1)^j\binom kj,
$$

so that its generating function can be written as

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{t\ge0}a_{t,k}z^t
&=\sum_{j\ge0}(-1)^j\binom kj\sum_{t\ge j}z^t=\sum_{j\ge0}(-1)^j\binom kj{z^j\over1-z} \\
&=-(1-z)^{k-1}=-\sum_{0\le t\le k-1}\binom{k-1}t(-z)^t.
\end{aligned}

Comparing coefficients gives

$$
a_{t,k}=(-1)^t\binom{k-1}t\quad k\ge1,
$$

Plugging $t=2J+1$ into this expression yields the desired inequality.